# Tracking last visited nodes - C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string as given below

```
string longText = "A CKJH VII D FZ A A A A A C C D";
```

Each word after a space is considered as a “word”. I need to print all words till I counter 5 same consecutive words. I have a working solution that does this. However, I would like to see whether there is any better way to do this. What is a better solution for this?

Note: This is **not** a homework problem. I have this requirement and I want to ensure I am using the best possible way.

**CODE**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> recentFive = new List<string>();

    string longText = "A CKJH VII D FZ A A A A A C C D";
    string[] namesArray = longText.Split(' ');
    List<string> namesList = new List<string>(namesArray.Length);
    namesList.AddRange(namesArray);

    foreach(string word in namesList)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(word);

        if (recentFive.Count < 5)
        {
            recentFive.Add(word);
        }
        else
        {
            recentFive[0] = recentFive[1];
            recentFive[1] = recentFive[2];
            recentFive[2] = recentFive[3];
            recentFive[3] = recentFive[4];
            recentFive[4] = word;

            if ((recentFive[0] == recentFive[1]) &&
                (recentFive[1] == recentFive[2]) &&
                (recentFive[2] == recentFive[3]) &&
                (recentFive[3] == recentFive[4]) )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Define 'better' so it's not quite so subjective. =)

Comment: @J.Steen Better == Easily readable , efficient and concise. (More priority to `readability`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string lastWord = null;
int consec = 1;
foreach(string word in namesList)
{
   Console.WriteLine(word);
   if ( lastWord != null )
   {
      if( lastWord == word ){
         consec++;
         if ( consec == 4 )
         {
            break;  // 5 consecutive..
         }
      }
      else{
        consec = 0;
      }
   }
   lastWord = word;
 }
```

Comment: Should probably initialize `consec` with `1`.

Answer (score 2):

If we take the time to first write a helper method that will group items while a given condition is met, we can write this:

```
var resultGroup = data.GroupWhile((prev, curr) => prev == curr)
    FirstOrDefault(group => group.Count() >= 5);
```

An implementation of this method is below:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhile<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        List<T> list = new List<T>() { iterator.Current };

        T previous = iterator.Current;

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!predicate(previous, iterator.Current))
            {
                yield return list;
                list = new List<T>();
            }

            list.Add(iterator.Current);
            previous = iterator.Current;
        }
        yield return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. However in my real scenario, the string is not static, it builds up dynamically.

Comment: @Lijo Okay.  I fail to see how that's a problem for this solution.  As long as you can create an `IEnumerable<string>` representing your words, this'll work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> TakeUntilDupesLimitReached( this IEnumerable<string> source , int limit , StringComparison comparisonType )
{
  if ( limit < 1 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("limit") ;

  string p = null ;
  int    n = 0 ;

  foreach ( string s in source )
  {
    bool areEqual = s.Equals( p ?? s , comparisonType ) ;

    n = 1 + ( areEqual ? n : 0 ) ;
    p = s ;

    yield return s ;

    if ( n >= limit ) break ;
  }

}
```

Then you can just say something along the lines of:

```
string[] x = "a b c d e e f f f g h i j".Split(new char[]{' '} , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) ;
string[] y = x.TakeUntilDupesLimitReached(3,StringComparison.Ordinal).ToArray() ;
```